# How Do Websites Restrict Reader View

Tags: javascript, html

Just wondering how news sites that require a subscription hide most of the article even in reader view? I have tried to inspect different news/article sites but can't figure it out. Some websites will recognize my computer and throw up a paywall, but reader view bypasses the paywall, while other websites will show the first paragraph followed by a 'Please login or sign up' paywall, even in reader view.

Answer (score 2):

Most of these sites show a blurred overlay and `overflow: hidden` on the `body` which you can easily remove as an advanced user. The best solution is not to send the article content at all (or truncated) in your backend response.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in a few different ways.

1. **Visually block and prohibit scrolling**: It's a super simple trick using CSS only. Adding `overflow: hidden;` on the `body` and perhaps adding a blurred overlay on top of everything will do the trick. If you want to be extra-prohibitive, you could shuffle/randomize the article body text with a little bit of JavaScript, so that even when readers remove the `CSS` properties the content still remains unreadable. Bypassing it by "Reader view" might fall somewhere around here, I suspect.
2. **Load content from the server**: Do not load/render content at initial page request. Check whether a user is logged in and authenticated for given content, then inject content from the server side. Here you cannot "bypass the paywall" because content only renders to authenticated users.